# How to hide ConnectionString in C# .Net 4.6 WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption, cryptography, connection-string

I have simple WPF Application working with SQL Server. What encryption algorythm I have to use to hide connection string from wpf application user? Please, don't offer middleware tier application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN for protecting your connection infromation.

In depth on how to encrypt configuration files using protected configuration is found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx).

Gist:

> **Use Windows Authentication**
>
> To help limit access to your data source, you must secure connection
>   information such as user ID, password, and data source name. In order
>   to avoid exposing user information, we recommend using Windows
>   authentication (sometimes referred to as integrated security) wherever
>   possible. Windows authentication is specified in a connection string
>   by using the Integrated Security or Trusted_Connection keywords,
>   eliminating the need to use a user ID and password. When using Windows
>   authentication, users are authenticated by Windows, and access to
>   server and database resources is determined by granting permissions to
>   Windows users and groups. For situations where it is not possible to
>   use Windows authentication, you must use extra care because user
>   credentials are exposed in the connection string. In an ASP.NET
>   application, you can configure a Windows account as a fixed identity
>   that is used to connect to databases and other network resources. You
>   enable impersonation in the identity element in the web.config file
>   and specify a user name and password.  The fixed identity account should be a low-privilege account that has been granted only necessary permissions
>   in the database. In addition, you should encrypt the configuration
>   file so that the user name and password are not exposed in clear text.
>
> **Encrypt Configuration Files**
>
> You can also store connection strings in configuration files, which
>   eliminates the need to embed them in your application's code.
>   Configuration files are standard XML files for which the .NET
>   Framework has defined a common set of elements. Connection strings in
>   configuration files are typically stored inside the
>    element in the app.config for a Windows
>   application, or the web.config file for an ASP.NET application. For
>   more information on the basics of storing, retrieving and encrypting
>   connection strings from configuration files, see Connection Strings
>   and Configuration Files.